# Get page referer and missing page that generates Error 404 using PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, superglobals

I've been researching online for a way to retrieve the **URL** that generates a **404 error**. I've found various postings on this subject in this and other sites and tried them all. Unfortunately I'm still not being able to get what I want. I will try to explain what I've done and what I'm getting.

### **SCENARIO:**

I have a page. Let's call **http://www.example.com/index.php**.

In this page, I have a link, to let's say **wrong_page.php** or, if you prefer, **http://www.example.com/index.php**.

As the page **wrong_page.php** doesn't really exists, When someone click on this link, it redirects to **error404.php**. (to make it easier, all pages are in the root directory.

**Question**: Is it possible for **error404.php** to give me both **index.php** as the original page where the wrong link resides and **wrong_page.php** as the wrong link itself?

### **SETUP**

At the root folder of my site I have  **.htaccess** file with the following directive:

```
ErrorDocument 404 error404.php
```

Inside **error404.php** I loop through the whole **$_SERVER** variable and, this is what I get:

1. If the visitor clicks on the **wrong_link** (the one that leads to **wrong_page.php**), 
   I get **$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] = 'index.php'** but no reference to **wrong_page.php**;
2. If the visitor types **wrong_page.php** in the address bar, **$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']** doesn't even exist (tested with *isset()* function).

Moreover, in both cases **$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = 'error404.php'**

I tried all **$*SERVER*** global variables starting with **"REDIRECT"** as mentioned in other postings, but they do not existed (also tested with *isset()* function).

Also, I tried this in two different servers: my own instance of WAMP (that I use for development) and a production server running apache.

In my computer, when I look at server error logs (**apache_error.log**), I find a line like this:

```
[Wed Jul 23 11:28:51 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /www.example.com  referer: /www.example.com/index.php
```

In the production server, this same line does not get created when I reproduce the same error.

What am I missing? Or is it all that I can get?
Are there any server parameters I can change to get what I want?
Is there another global variable I should look at?
As I said, I know there are many other postings regarding this, but they all talk about these same global variables and, as I said, they don't give me what I want (wrong_page.php as the culprit).

Comment: what you are missing is an understanding that http is a stateless protocol.

Comment: I appreciate your comment and the fact that http is a stateless protocol. Nevertheless, my question remains: is it possible to retrieve the wrong link (wrong_page.php) and, if so, do you know how or could you guide in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the "solution" if I can call it a solution.

The whole problem was in the URL used in the directive inside **.htaccess**.

I wrote my directive as being:

```
ErrorDocument 404 error404.php
```

But inside my actual **.htaccess** I had the directive as

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/error404.php
```

The presence of **http://www.example.com** was the problem. All I had to do was make the directive as follow:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error404.php
```

This way, **$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']** gives me the wrong URI requested by the user. If it is a link in my site, it will give me the page where the link exists in **$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']**. Otherwise, if the user simply typed the wrong URI in the address bar, **$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']** will be blank.

I hope this helps others with the same issue.